# Непонятное поведение цикла foreach

Tags: java

Есть поле экземпляра:

```
private int[] arr = new int[42];
```

Использую код:

```
for (int cell : arr) {
        cell = -1;
}
```

Я надеялась, что этот код заполнит массив элементами -1. Этого не случилось. Массив по-прежнему состоит из нулей.

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему так получилось. Какому коду эквивалентен цикл foreach в данном случае?

Comment: в foreach итерационная переменная доступна только для чтения.
[Примеры](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/java/for.php)

Comment: @UserName конечно же вы не правы, человек складывает в неё -1 и код компилируется, как она может быть доступна только для чтения? Если бы в массиве хранились объекты, а не примитивы, то их состояние можно было бы менять.

Comment: @IgorFedorov Я попробовала с Integer. Все равно нельзя менять массив с помощью for-each.

Comment: @iramm потому что объекты класса Integer не мутабельны, можно взять какой-нибудь класс вроде class Test{int x;}, и в foreach менять значения x, тогда в массиве будут отображаться изменения.

Comment: @IgorFedorov Спасибо за объяснение. Я проверила. Вы правы.

Comment: @IgorFedorov Но UserName может сослаться на авторитет Г.Шилдта. У него в Полном руководстве (8 издание) на с.135 говорится о доступности итерационной переменной "только для чтения". Но, очевидно, неявно предполагается использование примитивных типов.

Comment: Шильд наверняка немного другое писал, а что получилось - это неточности перевода. Или совсем старик из ума выжил.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Потому что этот цикл эквивалентен следующему

```
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    int cell = arr[i];   // получили копию i-го элемента
    cell = -1;           // изменили копию
}
```